# give read write permission to file

Tags: java, jsp

hello guys I want to give file permission to open in read mode or write mode
.ext contains file extention and file_name contains name of file. f_p is a veriable where I an geting input as 'r' or 'w' mode. Here I am using same file at different locations

But in this code I am getting error as
cannot find symbol: method setReadable(boolean)
location: fos2 is of type FileOutputStream

<%

some code here

FileInputStream fis2 = new   FileInputStream("e:/profile/epy/"+file_name+".ext");

```
        FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("e:/decrypt/"+file_name+"."+ext);

                    if(f_p.equals("R")||f_p.equals("r"))
                    {
                        fos2.setReadable(true);
                    }
                    else if(f_p.equals("W")||f_p.equals("w"))
                    {
                        fos2.setWritable(true);
                    }
```

// some code here

%>
https://jsfiddle.net/wc8pccyL/

Comment: Yep, the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) clearly show that `FileOutputStream` does not have a .setReadable() method. The File object, OTOH, does. So use `File` not `FileOutputStream`, and make friends with the Javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

The current code uses the wrong class (FileOutputStream).

```
File f = new File(SOME_PATH);
if ("r".equalsIgnoreCase(f_p)) {
   f.setReadable(true);
   ...
}
if ("w".equalsIgnoreCase(f_p)) {
   f.setWritable(true);
   ...
}
```

However, one should be careful in assuming that one would want write access without read access. The assumption in the OP's code is that the `f_p` has a single value of "R" or "W", and sets the permission. This assumption should be carefully checked, especially across operating systems.

Also, if the `FileOutputStream` has to be used later (for actual output), it has a constructor that takes a `File` object, so there is nothing lost by creating the `File` object in such a scenario, and then creating the `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);` where 'f' is the previously instantiated File object.

Comment: ThaNK YOU ....IT is solved :-)